# Ruby mail library How to get Error Reports

Tags: ruby, email

I'm using Ruby's mail library and it says you can get the error reports from mails you sent [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-error-reports-from-an-email).

I'm trying to figure out where I can find the path to check the mails that didn't get to the receivers due to the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure **receive method** to receive mails from **host** to you're app. As mentioned [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails).
In that **receiver** you'll configure where the mails to be stored. And from that path you can read & retrieve errors.

Without using any **receive method** you can read any `unread/not seen` mails from the mail and then you can get error reports.

You can check these [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150069/how-to-retrieve-only-unread-emails-with-ruby-mail-gem) & [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070204/message-eml-path-for-mail-gem-ruby-on-rails) to know about how to read mails.

Link about [Receive mail options](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails) in rails app.